# Any simplier way to 'read' enumerated types in pascal?

Tags: enums, pascal

User inputs an integer which corresponds to a value of defined enumerated type. I need to assign that value to variable **t**. This is what I thought of:

```
type test = (red,green,blue,fish);
var t:test;
    n,i:integer;
begin
  readln(n);
  t:=red;
  for i:=1 to n do
    t:=succ(t);
end.
```

Am I overcomplicating the task? Is it possible to write a simpler alogrithm?

Comment: Please note that `Ord(red) = 0` and using a generic notation `Ord(Low(test)) = 0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to just cast the integer to the enumerated type, for example:

```
t := test(n);
```

If you want to go the other way, then use `ord`:

```
n := ord(t);
```

That should let you move numerically to any item in the list. You can check the bounds with:

```
Ord(Low(test)))
```

and

```
Ord(High(test))
```

..where `test` is your type.